# x,y location of image corners in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have been working on a project and I need to get the x,y position of each corner in Image in a view.
Is it possible to achieve this?
I am building for macOS and I know I can get the x,y position of the image with GeometryReader but how can I get the x,y position of each corner?

[image]

I have tried to get the x,y with the following hack by assuming the initial position is 0,0:

```
.onTapGesture {
   print("Top left corner: \(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))")
   print("Top right corner: \(CGPoint(x: self.myImage.width, y: 0))")
   print("Bottom left corner: \(CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.myImage.height))")
   print("Bottom right corner: \(CGPoint(x: self.myImage.width, y: self.myImage.height))")
 }
```

Comment: Is it right to say that the one on top-left has like: (0.0,0.0) value for you? or you want global value? you are not clear in question! I see some padding as well in view, what about that?

Comment: @swiftPunk I'm using the Images inside an HStack and VStack so I want the global values.

Comment: Global value of view or monitor(Screen)?

Comment: @swiftPunk The image view.

Comment: It is possible can you show your tried code?

Comment: @swiftPunk I have updated the post and added the code I tried.

Comment: ok, give me some min! I post my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a way for you with **GeometryReader**:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            
            Image("ferrari")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .onTapGesture {
                    print("Top left corner: \(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))")
                    print("Top right corner: \(CGPoint(x: proxy.size.width, y: 0))")
                    print("Bottom left corner: \(CGPoint(x: 0, y: proxy.size.height))")
                    print("Bottom right corner: \(CGPoint(x: proxy.size.width, y: proxy.size.height))")
                }
            
        }
        .padding()
        
    }
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: What if you put the image in an HStack and VStack, resize it and centre it. How can you get the coordinates in that case knowing that the top left won't be 0,0?

Comment: There is other way reading size from background! but in both way you would get success! The issue is not what or where you put in the image, inside a HStack or VStack! all are the same process! I think you can try learning about GeometryReader first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method `func frame(in: CoordinateSpace) -> CGRect` on the Geometry Proxy, but you have to know in which `CoordinateSpace` you want the rectangle.  Do you want the size of the image view in its own coordinate space? The coordinate space of its superview?  The coordinate space of the window it resides in?  The coordinate space of the screen that contains the window...

Once you have a `CGRect` representing the view in some coordinate space then you can use methods like `minX`, `minY`, `maxX`, `maxY` on the rect to construct the four corners.